# schema validation error with spyne and soappy

Tags: django, python-2.7, spyne, soappy

I'm using Spyne to create simple webservie, and when i call that sample service i get following error :

```
faultType: <Fault senv:Client.SchemaValidationError: :10:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_CVC_ELT_1: Element 'testMethod': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.>


************************************************************************
*** Outgoing SOAP ******************************************************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<testMethod SOAP-ENC:root="1">
<name xsi:type="xsd:string">john</name>
</testMethod>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>



*** Incoming SOAP ******************************************************
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<senv:Envelope xmlns:senv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope  /"><senv:Body><senv:Fault>  <faultcode>senv:Client.SchemaValidationError</faultcode> <faultstring>:10:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_CVC_ELT_1: Element 'testMethod': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.</faultstring><faultactor></faultactor></senv:Fault></senv:Body></senv:Envelope>
```

---

## SERVICE

### views.py

```
class ServiceWsTest(ServiceBase):
    __namespace__ = "appname"

    @rpc(Unicode, _returns=Unicode)
    def testMethod(self, name):
        return "Hello {}" .format(name)

ws_test = csrf_exempt(DjangoApplication(Application([ServiceWsTest],
     'appname',
     in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
     out_protocol=Soap11(cleanup_namespaces=True),
     #interface=Wsdl11(),
)))
```

### urls.py

```
 url(r'^sample/service', DjangoView.as_view(
            services=[ServiceWsTest], tns='appname',
            in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'), 
            out_protocol=Soap11(cleanup_namespaces=True))),
```

### Service call using soappy

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL, SOAPProxy
server = SOAPProxy('http://IP ADDRESS/sandbox/sample/service/')
server.testMethod('john')
```

If I use suds, everything is working fine.

```
client = suds.client.Client("http://IP ADDRESS/sandbox/sample/service.wsdl", cache=None)
client.service.testMethod('jane')

Hello jane
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Soappy's request has two issues:

1. It's not using the correct namespace. `testMethod` tag must be in "appname" namespace. As there's no null namespace declaration (`xmlns="appname"`) in the document, the actual namespace of the tag is undefined.
2. It's using rpc encoding style (there are `xsi:type` attributes), whereas in the WSDL generated by Spyne, it explicitly says to use document encoding.

Don't use soappy, just use suds. To my knowledge, soappy hasn't been maintained for years.